# Facebook Instant Game fails to load scripts from cloudflare.com due to Content Security Policy

Tags: facebook, cloudflare, facebook-instant-games

In my Facebook Instant Game I try to statically load scripts from cloudflare.com such as:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.7/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.5/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

But getting Chrome browser error:

> Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.7/es5-shim.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.facebook.com connect.facebook.net cdn.mixpnl.com *.google-analytics.com web.localytics.com *.googletagmanager.com blob: *.cloudfront.net *.amazonaws.com *.googleapis.com *.firebaseapp.com *.firebaseio.com *.8686c.com *.cncovs.com *.aliyun.com *.aliyuncs.com *.wsdvs.com *.console.re *.kunlunar.com *.layabox.com *.windows.net *.msecnd.net *.anysdk.com cdn.trackjs.com cdn.firebase.com *.kochava.com *.akamaized.net *.cocos.com *.hinet.net *.playfab.com code.createjs.com *.zdassets.com websdk.appsflyer.com ". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Is there a way I can load scripts from cloudflare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) is one of the ways to mitigate XSS (cross-site scripting) attack on your site/app.

To allow your site/app to load scripts from `cdnjs.cloudflare.com`, you'll need to add/append the domain in the `script-src` directive of your `Content-Security-Policy` HTTP response header.

A few of [example implementations](https://content-security-policy.com/):

httpd.conf:

`Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' ...(snipped)... cdnjs.cloudflare.com;"`

nginx.conf:

`add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' ...(snipped)... cdnjs.cloudflare.com;";`

Then make sure to run checkconfig before reload or restart the httpd/nginx service.